# web scraping with selenium returns empty list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, iframe

I worked on little bit web scraping before but I have not idea of javascript. I want to scrape "Company Name" and "description of the company" from https://www.ces.tech/Show-Floor/Exhibitor-Directory.aspx. I am using selenium for scraping but I don't want to use browser in background. I write some code here:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import os
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
driver.get('https://www.ces.tech/Show-Floor/Exhibitor-Directory.aspx')
company = []
items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "exhibitorCardModal")
for item in items:
    comp=item.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "company-name")
    desc = item.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "description")
    result_dict = {
        "company":comp.text,
        "description":desc.text
    }
    company.append(result_dict)
```

But got empty list. Can someone tell me what is wrong here. I also try to use there api https://www.ces.tech/api/Exhibitors?searchTerm=&sortBy=alpha&alpha=&state=&country=&venue=&exhibitorType=&pageNo=1&pageSize=30 but got this error :

```
{"error":{"code":"ApiVersionUnspecified","message":"An API version is required, but was not specified."}}
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer resolved your problems?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But got an error "TimeoutException: Message:" On this line "wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "exhibitorCardModal")))"

Comment: I see.. Please try the updated version

Comment: still "items" got spaces means empty.

Comment: @SarlaDevi  `items` is a list of web elements, not texts. you can not print it. Is that list is empty?

Comment: @Prophet I understand what I was doing wrong. Thx

Comment: So, my answer resolved your problem?

Comment: your answer was helpful. I also used other tools like beautiful soup and more for loops and if-else condition.

Answer (score 1):

1. You also have to add wait / delay before accessing the elements to let the page completely loaded before you trying to access them.
2. You should use `find_element` instead of `find_elements` for the loop internal commands:

```py
comp=item.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "company-name")
desc = item.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "description")
```

So your code should be something like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://www.ces.tech/Show-Floor/Exhibitor-Directory.aspx')

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "exhibitorCardModal")))
time.sleep(0.5)
company = []
items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "exhibitorCardModal")
for item in items:
    comp=item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "company-name")
    desc = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "description")
    result_dict = {
        "company":comp.text,
        "description"::desc.text
    }
    company.append(result_dict)
```